# What is the equivalent of Postgres' array overlap (&&) function in GraphQL?

Tags: javascript, postgresql, graphql, apollo, hasura

In Postgres, the [overlap ("&&") operator](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/functions-array.html) of arrays are used to check if two arrays have any element in common.

For example,

| Query | Result |
| --- | --- |
| ARRAY[1,4,3] && ARRAY[2,1] | true |
| ARRAY[1,4,3] && ARRAY[2,5] | false |

**Is there anything similar in GraphQL?**

Also, is there anything I can use in Hasura for this?

---

- A more specific real use case I can think of is as follows. (I just made them up just for clarification and did not run or validate the syntax.)

```
// Assume a you want to find all restaurants with any of the selected cuisines.

const restaurantA = {..., cuisineType: ['Fusion', 'Chinese', 'Japanese', 'Korean']}
const restaurantB = {..., cuisineType: ['Vegetarian', 'Thai']}
const restaurantC = {..., cuisineType: ['European']}

// Assume the data above is stored in Postgres (as an array in column field, not using a bridge table.

const SQL_1 = "SELECT * 
               FROM restaurants 
               WHERE cuisine_type && ['Korean', 'Japanese']" // Expect restaurantA and restaurantC
const SQL_2 = "SELECT * 
               FROM restaurants 
               WHERE cuisine_type && ['Vegetarian', 'European']" // Expect restaurantB and restaurantC

### GOAL: I want to use GraphQL, Apollo, Hasura to have the same effect as SQL_1 and SQL_2
```

Comment: Maybe you can combine the `any` [nested object operator](https://hasura.io/docs/latest/graphql/core/databases/postgres/queries/query-filters.html#fetch-if-any-of-the-nested-objects-defined-via-an-array-relationship-satisfy-a-condition) with the `in` [operator](https://hasura.io/docs/latest/graphql/core/databases/postgres/queries/query-filters.html#list-based-search-operators-in-nin)?

Comment: I just noticed that this only works if cuisineType is not an inlined array but instead a joined relationship (maybe this is the better thing to do in the first place?)

Comment: I'm looking for a GraphQL specific solution. And yes I considered adding a bridge table, but I don't really want to make a table that has 10~20 rows max, and then another table to just store the relationships.

Comment: What you think is "GraphQL specific" really is just Hasura specific. The GraphQL spec does not specify filters, operators or anything like that. Putting generic filters on list fields is what Hasura is offering in their product but very few GraphQL APIs do that. It is not part of any standard.